# What is this TV movie that used the Voight Kampff test?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a TV movie, probably starring Dennis Farina as the principal actor (the cop), in which the Voigt Kampff test was used as a detective tool.

I really believe that they mentioned  the VKT explicitly and they had the machine also. As the part showing the machine was filmed in a luminous house in the daylight, I was impressed by some details, because in Blade Runner there was not too much shown about the device.

The rare thing was that in that TV movie there were no droids or robots. The use of the test was, as I pointed out, "detective"... Probably in a way to make a better test which, by means of detecting the (lack of) empathy, the cop was capable to trace (as I remembered vaguely) a serial killer or something.

I don't remember more, only that this telefilm was more recent than "Manhunter" (1986), the first version of "Red Dragon".

I didn't annotate anything about it and now I am asking myself if that film really existed. It was a made-for-TV movie, not a serial.

Comment: I assume you mean the test from *Bladerunner*? Was it mentioned by that name? Were there indeed robots or androids/gynoids in the film? When did you watch it? What network?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - OP will mean a VK *style* test, since no such film exists based on Blade Runner.

Comment: The rare thing was that in that tv movie there were no droids or robots. Your assumption is right is the Test to identify replicants in Blade Runner.  In that tv movie the use of the test was, as I pointed out, "detective"... Probably in a way to make a better test which, by means of detecting the (lack of) empathy, the cop was capable to trace (as I remembered vaguely) a serial killer or something so... But I don´t remember more, only that probably Dennis Farina was the principal actor (the cop) and that this telefilm was more recent than "the man hunter" (first version of "Red Dragon").

Comment: So was this a literal testing device (like the [VK](https://media.tenor.com/uTs1dO4BV_EAAAAd/eye-blade-runner.gif)) or did he simply ask a bunch of questions designed to detect empathy in the respondent?

Comment: As I already said I don´t remember much about this telefilm, but I really believe that they mentioned explicitelt the VKT and they had the machine also. As the part showing the machine was filmed in a luminous house in the daylight, I was impressed by some details showed, because in Blade Runner there were no too much showed about the device...

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001199/

Comment: Did you watch this in the 80s? The 90s? Last year?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6270374/ has the Voight-Kampff test, but it looks like the robots may exist there.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That show is available on YouTube. It's some sort of wannabe-SNL sketch show

Comment: Not to be a wet blanket, but it seems like the movie might not be sci-fi? What sci-fi elements were in the movie?

Comment: The test purports to be scientific, but is fictional - would that make the film count as on-topic? @ToddWilcox

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I guess it depends - it’s not clear whether it’s the actual VK test or merely a mundane polygraph or something like that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qrTgxuOHGo

Comment: @ToddWilcox - A fake futuristic-y polygraphy thing would still be on-topic since the question is specifically about that one SF'al element.

Comment: @Valorum Sounds like James Bond is on topic. Which is fine, just… unexpected

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Certain aspects of James Bond have always been on topic, but the whole film series isn't, because most of it is spy fiction, not sci fiction

Comment: I'm not finding much science fiction in Dennis Farina's filmography.

Answer (score 2):

IMDB suggests a few possibilities.

series: Orphan Black
episode: [Transitory Sacrifices of Crisis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4277160/movieconnections/?ref_=tt_trv_cnn)

> SPOILER: When Paul is testing the Castor clones, the test equipment and process is nearly identical to the 'Voight-Kampff' machine utilised by Blade Runners to detect Replicants. Both the film and this series deal with issues about the nature of being human and whether an external observer can identify a true human from a 'copy' made through advanced technology.

Series: Stargate SG-1
Episode: [Divide and Conquer](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709073/movieconnections/?ref_=tt_trv_cnn)

> The testing device used is similar to the Voight-Kampff

Series: Space: Above and Beyond
Episode: [Eyes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706362/movieconnections/?ref_=tt_trv_cnn)

> The loyalty test given to the 'InVitros' is based on the Voight Kampff test used to detect 'Replicants' in Blade Runner.